# The connection to the host server failed. Java

Tags: sql-server, database, connection-string

I'm trying to run a query but I keep getting this error:

The connection to the host server=localhost, named instance sqlexpress failed. Error: "java.net.UnknownHostException: server=localhost". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.

Any ideas? Here's my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            try {
                // TODO code application logic here
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

           // Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/myDatabase; instance = SQLEXPRESS","sa","password");
            String Connectionurl="jdbc:sqlserver://server=Owner-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; DatabaseName=myDatabase;";
            Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(Connectionurl,"sa","password");
             Statement myStmt  = dbConnection.createStatement();

                String query = "INSERT INTO People(ID, Name, Surname, Age, Contact, Location, Course) VALUES"
                        + " (1007, 'Elroy', 'Smith', 33, 21366688, 'Somewhere', 'somecourse')";

                myStmt.executeUpdate(query);


                myStmt.executeQuery(query);

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you connect to your local database?

Comment: I think that is the problem. I could do it from C# but not from here. Ive been playing around with connection strings all day

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2606653/2291

Answer (score 2):

There is one interesting site at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Based on this, i think connect URL should be:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://Owner-PC;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS;DatabaseName=myDatabase;
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the answer for [Connecting to SQL Server 2008 from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2606712/2291) by [Venkatesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/277516/venkatesh):

> Try following connection,

```
 String Connectionurl="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=myDatabase"
```