# Login failed for user gagan(JDBC, MS SQL Server)

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

I have SQL Server Installed and now I want to use it for JDBC connectivity. I have enabled the TCP/IP connection via manager and Mixed mode authentication via Object explorer properties. 
Now my connection statement says

```
Class.forName( "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" ); // no error
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=student;user=gagan;password=35795200");
```

where gagan is my username and 35795200 is my windows login password. I still get the login failed exception.
I am really fed up with this. Please help !

Comment: are you sure the localhost:1433 is correct?

Comment: yes. there is no error regarding the port no

Comment: Hang on... Why are you using your windows login password to login to a database? Unless they are both identical. I hope there is an exiting database user "gagan".

Comment: I am using windows authentication as shown here 

http://i58.tinypic.com/2lk5ra9.jpg

if this is wrong, then what should i use to login to my database ?

Comment: From the stack trace, you're using an incorrect username/password to login to the DB. Firstly, make sure the user exists in the DB. I am not familiar wit SQL server but i expect it to have an administrator interface for you to create database user. Once that is done, test it using a SQL client. When u can login with the SQl client, then try again with JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL includes username and password. Try calling getConnection(URL, username, password) method. URL is in the form jdbc:subprotocol:subname

Comment: Same error @anonymous
tried calling
DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=student","gagan","35759200");
also

Comment: the exception was too long to be posted as a comment, so i have posted the screenshot here :

http://i62.tinypic.com/29akn8.jpg

Comment: Put it in your problem description. Every bit of info helps.

Comment: I am a beginner in JDBC. I have not worked in any of the databases. I have SQL server 2008 installed, JDBC libraries added into my eclipse project and now i am trying to connect to the server  but i am not able to. The problem (Exception) is shown in the screenshot whose link was posted in the comment above

Answer (score 0):

It may be `database=` not `databasename`. If that does not work, check if you are able to login with these credentials. Instead of this, There is nothing wrong with connection string. Specify which version of MSSQL you are using.

```
Class.forName( "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" ); // no error
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:sqlserver://WAHEGURU_HP;database=student;user=WAHEGURU\\gagan;password=35795200");
```

Comment: According to this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606653/connecting-to-sql-server-2008-from-java "databaseName" is correct.

Comment: I am using 2008 version of SQL. I tried removing database name, that is not a problem because error still persists. I think the thing which is wrong, is the username and/or password

Comment: I have updated the connectionstring in my answer. Copy and try to use. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

1. databasename is correct parameter for connection string
2. Please confirm with your DBA if you are using correct port "://localhost:**1433**;"
   1433 is default port but some times dba's use different ports as well
3. check if you login password is actually correct by connecting to sql server using ssms.

**Examples of connection string:**

/********************************************************/
Connect to the default database on the local computer by using integrated authentication:

jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;integratedSecurity=true;

Connect to a named database on a remote server:

jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;

Connect on the default port to the remote server:

jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;

Connect by specifying a customized application name:

jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;applicationName=MyApp;

/********************************************************/

Please paste screen shot of error , this will help to resolve this